# Trying to see how much of a level of a variable is in another level of another variable

Tags: r, variables

I am trying to figure out how to see how much of a certain variable is in another variable. What I mean is that I have two variables in R, and they both have two levels. I want to see how much of level 2 of Variable 1 is in level 2 of Variable 2, but I cannot figure out how. I cannot figure out which command or lines of code I need to input in order to get my desired out come. They are both categorical data.

I am new to R, and I have not been able to find any answers yet. I am hoping that you guys will be able to help.

To get more in depth, I am trying to compare smokers to premature birth. I have two variables, habit, and premature. Habit has two levels, non smokers and smokers. Premature has two levels, premature birth and full term. I want to see how many smokers are in the premature births or visa versa.

I am expecting a number, and it needs to be how much of level 2 of variable 1 is in level 2 of variable 2.

Comment: Take a look at `?table`.

Comment: That was what I was looking for thank you! The number came out to be 19, but do you know how I can make that into its own variable?

Comment: According to `?table`, `table()` returns a contingency table which is an array of integer values. You can pick specific values by subsetting, e.g., `table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$am)[2,2]`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!!